# C# lambda expression with list of custom type elements

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I'm trying to get List of custom type elements with specific condition using lambda expression inside FindAll(), namely:

```
private static List<RoadSegment> FindNodeSegments(Node currentNode)
    {
        List<RoadSegment> currentSegments =  allSegments.FindAll(segment => segment.Nodes.Contains(currentNode));

        return currentSegments;
    }
```

but I'm getting empty list as a result. I can't find the error here.
Custom class:

```
public class RoadSegment
{
    public double Length { get; set; }

    public double MaxSpeed { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm looking for every element containing given Node element in it's Nodes list.
The input I'm using:

```
        // Test 0
        Node node1 = new()
        {
            AbsolutePosition = new double[2] { 0, 0 },
            Id = 1,
            NodesConnected = new() {2}
        };

        Node node2 = new()
        {
            AbsolutePosition = new double[2] { 10, 0 },
            Id = 2,
            NodesConnected = new() { 1 }
        };

        List<RoadSegment> segments = new()
        {
            new()
            {
                Length = 10,
                MaxSpeed = 30,
                Nodes = new() { node1, node2 }
            }

        };
```

currentNode is correct Element, the problem is with lambda expression.

EDIT 1: Node Def

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public double[] AbsolutePosition { get; set; }

    public List<int>? NodesConnected { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2: Program.cs and allSegments value set

Program.cs

```
List<RoadSegment> segments = MapLoadingSystem.MapLoader.LoadMap();

RoadSegment seg1 = segments.First(); 
Console.WriteLine(MapRouteFinder.RouteFinder.FindRoute(seg1.Nodes[0], 
seg1.Nodes[1]));
```

All segments:

```
allSegments = MapLoadingSystem.MapLoader.LoadMap();
```

Comment: Please add `Node` definition

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D3GplJ), your code works if we fill in the gaps ourselves.

Comment: @complikator added

Comment: Are the references for currentNode and nodes in the target lists the same? If not you'll need to override the Equals method for Node or define and IEqualityComparer

Comment: Those are the same

Comment: For me this code works, if you still have problems show us your `main`

Comment: @complikator added Program.cs

Comment: Are you sure your allSegments collection has the same ref you're passing in as currentNode? This code works fine.

Comment: @HasaniH I've added set of allSegments and the call for the function, in this context the currentNode call in lambda function is seg.Nodes[0]

Comment: When I run the code I got exception that returned currentSegments list is empty -  $exception {"Sequence contains no elements"} System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Yea but unless you can show that LoadMap() is reusing references rather than creating new references with the same values you haven't answered my question. If you grab currentNode directly from allSegments what happens?

Comment: @KubaJ I think there is a problem with your `MapRouteFinder`

Comment: I've added whole code of MapRouteFinder to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/6AM6ZRQ7

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, actually @HasaniH was right, the thing was all about references etc. I've changed the approach to make the function truly static and all in all the solution is given below, with this everything works:

```
public static Route FindRoute(Node startPoint, Node destinationPoint, List<RoadSegment> allSegments, string routePriority = "balanced")
    {

        Node currentNode = startPoint;

        List<Node> nodes = new() {currentNode};

        double totalCost = 0;

        while (currentNode != destinationPoint)
        {
            Tuple<Node, double> nextStepParams = FindNextStep(currentNode, allSegments);

            Node nextNode = nextStepParams.Item1;

            totalCost += nextStepParams.Item2;

            nodes.Add(nextNode);

            currentNode = nextNode;
        }

        return new()
        {
            TotalCost = totalCost,
            Nodes = nodes
        };
    }

    private static Tuple<Node, double> FindNextStep(Node currentNode, List<RoadSegment> segments)
    {
        Node nextNode = currentNode; 
        
        List<RoadSegment> currSegments = segments.FindAll(segment => segment.Nodes.Contains(currentNode));

        double currCost = StepCost(currSegments.First(), currentNode, CoeffFunction());

        double currSegmentCost;

        foreach (RoadSegment segment in currSegments)
        {
            currSegmentCost = StepCost(segment, currentNode, CoeffFunction());

            currCost = Math.Min(currCost, currSegmentCost);
            
            if (currSegmentCost == currCost)
            {
                int currSegmentNodeId = segment.Nodes.IndexOf(currentNode);

                nextNode = segment.Nodes[1 - currSegmentNodeId];
            }
        }

        Tuple<Node, double> result = Tuple.Create(nextNode, currCost);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: FWIW I still think you should override Equals or define an IEqualityComparer for your Node and possible your RoadSegment. I suspect checking value equivalence will be useful in multiple parts of your project